# Can I get my degree revoked for misuse of citations?

Tags: phd, citations, degree

I have been accused of not correctly attributing a person in my PhD dissertation that was finished several years ago. The person claimed he would bring the matter to the university I did my PhD at. I revised the text and the in-text references to this person's sources are there and in the bibliografy, but I realize that they could have been clearer references (same for cases of previous chapters that I noted in my re-reading). It was never my intention to plagiarize, though I know that is not important for these matters. Is is a case that could cost me my degree? I do not know how to react. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. Unfortunately, we won't be able to give you a personalized answer -- there are many "individual factors," and your university's policies, procedures, and personalities are hard to predict. But, we have distilled all our wisdom on this topic into a "canonical question" -- see the link above. Good luck.

Comment: I apologize for the previous repetiton. I had missed this! Thank you.

Comment: I doubt you have any problems here. The in-text reference are there, and even if they aren't, people make mistakes. A PhD dissertation is a huge document often with hundreds of references. Mistakes happen. Don't worry about it too much. Just apologise for any mistakes.